# React Context Consumer Does Not Update Attributes

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-context, react-component

I can successfully see how React Context updates my values in the Consumer for the text, but it fails to update values inside any attributes. Basically, Consumer seems to keep old default values when inline, generated during the build, while it updates text inside tags just fine.

Here is what I have:

`appcontext.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
const AppContext = React.createContext({});
export default AppContext;
```

`layout.js`:

```
import AppContext from "./AppContext"
import PlaceHelper from "./placehelper"
//...
const placeHeloper = PlaceHelper();
const currentPlaceData = placeHeloper.getCurrentPlaceData();
let [placeData, setPlaceData] = useState({ ...currentPlaceData })
//...
return (
 <>
  <AppContext.Provider value={placeData}>
    <main>{children}</main>
  </AppContext.Provider>
 </>
)
```

then I use Consumer in the component:

`home.js`:

```
import AppContext from "../AppContext"
//...
<div id="content">
  <AppContext.Consumer>
    { value =>
<header noupdate={value.banner} style={{backgroundImage: "url(" + value.banner + ")"}}>
        {/* UPDATES BELOW SUCCESSFULLY */}
        {value.banner}
//...
```

In an example above, the `value.banner` gets updated when it is inside the `header` tag but it fails to be updated when it is inside the `style` attribute or `noupdate` attribute. I cannot understand why.

Comment: What is this `noupdate` property?  It seems like it's preventing updates...as intended?

Comment: I added `noupdate` property as an example so it is easy to understand that this does not update a value. You can ignore it and just look at the `style` property instead.

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example (eg. sandbox?). I really kind of hard to understand what went wrong otherwise :)

Comment: `value.banner` may not be the appropriate value for `style.backgroundImage` or `noupdate` attribute. If the DOM attribute is not correct, the browser ignores them altogether. check if the value is appropriate for the given attribute first. if the problem persists, we can discuss further from there.